# Correlation Id and Message Id in IBM MQ

Tags: c++, c, ibm-mq

For a c++ and c program, I am trying to set a value for msgId or CorrelId for a particular message in IBM MQ, that will be later put to a topic. But there's an error of "Expression must be a modifiable L-value" for both the ids.

I defined the ids as

```
MQBYTE24 MsgId;
MQBYTE24 CorrelId;
```

and the MQMD is defined as default:

```
MQMD md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};
```

I cannot use the #define directive as I am trying to single out a message to be put to a topic from the publisher's end. Receive all the messages for subscriber and check for the particular message.

Is my approach of using correlIds or MsgIds correct or is there a better way for doing this?

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually try to put the value into the MsgId or CorrelId? i.e. the line of code with the error "Expression must be a modifiable L-value" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect you to have some code that looks like the following:-

```
memcpy(md.CorrelId, CorrelId, MQ_MSG_ID_LENGTH);
```

Please also remember that the message ID that you MQPUT to a topic does not end up at the subscribers. A new message ID is created for each copy of the published message that is given to each subscriber. You should use the Correlation ID instead to have it flow through to the subscriber, and ensure the subscribers are made correctly to receive the publishers correlation ID.

Read [IBM MQ Little Gem #31: Publisher's CorrelId](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/morag-hughson/2018/01/27/ibm-mq-little-gem-31-publishers-correlid) for more information about this.

Comment: According to the community page, if we set a publishers correlation id then the topic's id will get removed and subscribers will have to filter using that id.  What I wanted to achieve was that send the messages as topic's correlation id and have a way to single out a particular message received like say a checksum using message descriptors if possible. this particular message is needed to terminate the subscriber applications once it receives the message.

Comment: Sounds like you should add a message property. That's a good way to add arbitrary meta-data to a message. You don't have the length restrictions or the above issue if you do that.

Comment: in the documentation it is given "A property name is a character string." but

when I add the name like this : 
MQCHARV  Name[] = "timestamp";
this error comes: 
initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate objectC/C++(520)


and when I try to initialize it as a string like this:
MQCHARV  Name = "timestamp";
this error comes:
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [10]" to "tagMQCHARV"C/C++(415)

Comment: An MQCHARV is not a string, it contains a string. Please raise a new question and we can provide an answer for this. Alternatively have a look at IBM supplied samples which illustrate the use of message properties in C code.

Comment: Could you point out the sample file in the mqm directory?

Comment: When I grep for MQSETMP I find the sample amqsstma.c